# UnavailableError: Socket closed-Error on google colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, model, google-colaboratory

I am trying to save my model using vae.save(local_vae_model_path, save_format='h5'). But I keep getting this error

```
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:worker/replica:0/task:0:
:{"created":"@1681842679.947866937","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.64.176.194:8470","file":"external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Socket closed","grpc_status":14}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?